# How many elements in a field of size $3^4 (81)$ have multiplicative order $20$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, finite-fields

I'm looking at the fact that the set of multiplicative inverses has order 80 and is cyclic. Since 20 divides 80 can we say using  euler's function it is 8? It seems too simple for the number of points the question gets. I'm also getting confused with the fact that the order of an element divides the order of the group (and a field is a group) but 20 doesn't divide 81?

Comment: $20$ does divide $80$.

Comment: The group in question is the multiplicative group of the field (not the additive group), and the element $0$ is not in the multiplicative group.

Comment: The multiplicative group has $80$ elements (zero is excluded), so it is cyclic of that order.

Comment: $\phi(20)=8$ is the correct.answer. The multiplicative group is cyclic of order $80$, hence it has a **unique** (also cyclic) subgroup of order $20$, and within that subgroup there are $\phi(20)$ elements of order $20$. After proving the fact that the multiplicative group pof the field is cyclic everything else follows from the properties of cyclic groups.

Comment: Thanks all, seems like I was on the right track, I need to have faith in myself!